# Sorting tree nodes in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working with JSF 2.1 and Primefaces 3.3. I am using the primefaces tree component for crating the tree from Database. I wanted to sort the tree nodes in alphabetical order at all levels. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to sort Primefaces `DefaultTreeNode` objects at the ManagedBean using `Collections.sort` and a Comparator class.

```
public TreeNodeComparator() implements Comparator<TreeNode> {
  public int compare(TreeNode n1, TreeNode n2) {
    // This assumes the tree node data is a string
    return n1.getData().compareTo(n2.getData());
  }
}
```

In your managed bean you will need to assemble your child lists without adding their parents yet.  That can come later.  For right now build your child lists out for each level and set the `parent` to `null`;

```
TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("node1", null);
TreeNode node2 = new DefaultTreeNode("node2", null);
TreeNode child1node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("zgnagn", null);
TreeNode child2node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("vvnieeianag", null);
TreeNode child1node2 = new DefaultTreeNode("cajkgnagair", null);
TreeNode child2node2 = new DefaultTreeNode("ajaavnagwokd", null);
rootNodeChildren.add(node1);
rootNodeChildren.add(node2);
node1Children.add(child1node1);
node1Children.add(child2node1);
node2Children.add(child1node2);
node2Children.add(child2node2);
```

The reason why we are setting everything to null is because when the parent is set on the DefaultTreeNode it is added to the parents child list.  The order in which you set a nodes parents determines the order they will appear in the Tree component.

Knowing that we can use our comparator to sort each list individually.

```
Collections.sort(rootNodeChildren, new TreeNodeComparator());
Collections.sort(node1Children, new TreeNodeComparator());
Collections.sort(node2Children, new TreeNodeComparator());
```

Now all of the lists are sorted so we can loop through and the appropriate parents one at a time. You can probably write an algorithm to determine this or you can keep a separate data stucture that builds the tree hierarchy without adding to the list.

Another way, and probably easier overall, is to just override the DefaultTreeNode class and give it a sort method:

```
public SortableDefaultTreeNode extends DefaultTreeNode {

  public void sort() {
    TreeNodeComparator comparator = new TreeNodeComparator();
    Collections.sort(this.children, comparator);
    for (TreeNode child : children) {
      child.sort();
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can just build your TreeNodes out and then call `root.sort()` and it will recursively sort all of its children at each level alphabetically.

Comment: Thank you maple_shaft. It saved my day.

Comment: Please check your answer because the class ```java.util.Collections``` has 2 versions of ```sort``` method. Both expect a parameter of type ```java.util.List<T>``` which is incompatible with ```TreeNode```  type.

Answer (score 7):

we had problems with the sorting via `Comparator` and found out, that there is a handy **PrimeFaces [TreeUtils.sortNode( TreeNode, Comparator )](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/util/TreeUtils.html#sortNode%28org.primefaces.model.TreeNode,%20java.util.Comparator%29)** class **already provided** which works like a charm :)

Comment: This one is really the best solution and simple as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a generic comparable TreeNode aproach such as:

*Base was taken from primefaces `DefaultTreeNode`, unmodified changes are left out in below code.*

If child's should not be restricted on T one can use `TreeNodeComparable<T extends Comparable<?>>` and cast to `Comparable` in `compareTo()` method.

```
public class TreeNodeComparable<T extends Comparable<T>> implements TreeNode, Serializable,
    Comparable<TreeNodeComparable<T>>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = ...;

    private T data;

    private List<TreeNodeComparable<T>> children;


    public TreeNodeComparable(final String type, final T data, final TreeNodeComparable<T> parent)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.data = data;
        this.children = (List) new TreeNodeChildren(this);
        if (parent != null)
            parent.getChildren().add(this);
    }

    /**
     * Comparison only depends on the underlying data
     * 
     * @see ObjectUtils#compare(Comparable, Comparable)
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(final TreeNodeComparable<T> node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("node");

        return ObjectUtils.compare((T) this.getData(), (T) node.getData());
    }

    /**
     * Recursively sorts the complete tree.
     */
    public void sort()
    {
        Collections.sort(this.children);
        for (final TreeNodeComparable<T> child : this.children)
        {
            child.sort();

            // must reset parent due to PF problems
            // http://forum.primefaces.org/posting.php?mode=reply&f=3&t=39752
            child.setParent(this);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null || this.getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;

        final TreeNodeComparable<T> other = (TreeNodeComparable<T>) obj;

        return ObjectUtils.equals(this.data, other.data);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return new HashCodeBuilder().append(this.data).toHashCode();
    }

    public void setData(final Object data)
    {
        if (data != null && !(data instanceof Comparable))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.data = (T) data;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings(
    {
        "unchecked", "rawtypes"
    })
    public List<TreeNode> getChildren()
    {
        return (List) this.children;
    }
}
```