# Collection not sorted in expected order, e.g. ąąą is coming after zzz

Tags: java, sorting, jsf, primefaces, tree

There was very similar question, asked some time ago :

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891739/sorting-tree-nodes-in-primefaces)

What I have is this :
[image]

sorted WRONG as we can see.

**Bean file:**

```
init(){
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
        createFolderTree(folderManager.getSiteFolderId(),root);
        Collections.sort(root, new TreeNodeComparator());
    }

public void createFolderTree(String id, TreeNode root) {
        List<CmisObject> childrenList = new ArrayList<>();
        ItemIterable<CmisObject> children = folderManager.getFolderChildren(id);
        Iterator<CmisObject> iterator = children.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            childrenList.add(iterator.next());
        }
        Collections.sort(childrenList, new TreeNodeComparator(SortOrder.ASCENDING));

          if (children.getPageNumItems() > 0) {
            for (CmisObject o : childrenList) {
                if (o.getBaseTypeId().toString() != "CMIS_DOCUMENT") {
                    TreeNode newNode = new DefaultTreeNode(o, root);
                    createFolderTree(o.getId(), newNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comparator

```
public class TreeNodeComparator implements Comparator<CmisObject> {

private SortOrder sortOrder;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public TreeNodeComparator(SortOrder sortOrder) {
    this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
}

@Override
public int compare(CmisObject n1, CmisObject n2) {
    try {

         Object value1 = n1.getName();
         Object value2 = n2.getName();

        String simple = "< a< ą< b < c < č < d < e < ę < i < į < y< j < k < l < s < š< t< u < ų< v < z < ž ";
        RuleBasedCollator lt_LTCollator = new RuleBasedCollator(simple);
        Collator lithuanianCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("lt_LT"));
        lt_LTCollator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
        int value = lt_LTCollator.compare(value1.toString(), value2.toString());

        return SortOrder.ASCENDING.equals(sortOrder) ? value : -1 * value;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}


public SortOrder getSortOrder() {
    return sortOrder;
}


public void setSortOrder(SortOrder sortOrder) {
    this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
}
```

}

Also I  tried to  do it in a same way as in a link posted before, but  I get that my sort is not applicable for this..

Maybe I am mising something very simple, but this starts to annoy me.
Any help would be nice,

and.. I know that root is not a List :)

But.. is there a way, to do sorting like this.

**EDIT:**

So I updated my code a bit, comparator working as it Should, I tested it on

```
List<String> aa = Arrays.asList("ž", "a", "aa", "c", "ąąą", "ęęę", "ąą", "vv", "žžž", "zz", "ėėė");
```

and output was:

```
[a, aa, ąą, ąąą, c, ėėė, ęęę, vv, zz, ž, žžž]
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a JSF specific problem. JSF is merely the model view presenter here. You'd have had exactly the same problem when presenting the already-prepared model to the view in a different way, such as `System.out.println()`.

Let me demonstrate:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("zzz", "ąąą", "žžž", "ššš", "aaa", "sss");
Collections.sort(strings);
System.out.println(strings);
```

> [aaa, sss, zzz, ąąą, ššš, žžž]

This sorting is according the English rule. This is the default behavior when you sort without a [language-specific](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/locale.html) [collation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/rule.html) using the [`java.text.Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) API.

In below example I'll assume you're interested in Polish collation rules.

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("zzz", "ąąą", "žžž", "ššš", "aaa", "sss");
Collections.sort(strings, Collator.getInstance(new Locale("pl")));
System.out.println(strings);
```

> [aaa, ąąą, sss, ššš, zzz, žžž]

You'll need to change your `TreeNodeComparator` to take this into account. As you're in JSF context, consider extracting the locale from `UIViewRoot#getLocale()`.

Comment: So you mean to say that your comparator is actually never invoked?

Comment: Yes, correct,  I can't check if this comparator will work for me, because, if you check code, 

root is new DefaultTreeNode and comparator want a List<String>  I am still new to comparator, and kinda first/second time I need to use..

What I mean is, I dont know how to pass my folderTree to comparator.

Comment: You should sort `children` instead.

Comment: will try to do that tomorrow, after I'll get to work and will post back here, 

Thanks for helping Balus !

Comment: So.. I did as you said,  I called my comparator on children  but still, 

all letters like     ą, š, ž  goes after normal letter like   a, s, z ...

updated my code

Comment: I am using same comparator in some other places, it does the job.

by same, I mean rule based.

Comment: Print/log the children before and after sorting. If they are indeed properly sorted afterwards, then your comparator is all fine. Maybe it's just the way you're populating the tree which makes them disorted again. You should perhaps take that into account inside the comparator.

Comment: Yes... I was stupid enought all this time, and now I see at this situacion, my comparator is doing something wrong... I mean, comparator must be the problem,.. 

as, @Kukeltje  asked, I did tried use it just on regulart String, and  yes.. its not working as it shoud, for some reason.. so at least now  I know where the problem is coming form.. 

after I find how to fix it, will share

Comment: So.. I Edited code a bit, comparator works as it should on simple List<string>,  ( check post to see )  but when I try to sort my FolderTree it does not work as it should..

I begin to feel broken..

Comment: So finally, as I thought code was almost OK,  did some small fixes, but biggest fail was, that all for had some sort added, which I mised,  so now it works... last what I need to do is, to sort capital letter before lower case letters.. and  thats it..   

So I think, I can close this question, and big thanks goes to @BalusC and Kukeltje ..

thanks guys